# Exclude posts without category from loop

Tags: categories, filters, loop

I'm trying to exclude all the posts that doesn't have a category assigned to from the main loop, i searched everywhere and i found a billion ways to exclude some categories or filter from specific category but not what i need to do, is it possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Raffaele:**

The function `wp_get_object_terms(...)` can provide you with the information you need. I've written a `has_category($post_id)` function that can be used in the loop like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php if (has_category($post->ID)): ?>
      <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here is the `has_category()` function:

```
<?php
function has_category($post_id) {
  $has_category = false;
  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id,'category');
  if (is_array($terms)) {
    foreach($terms as $index => $term)
      if ($term->slug=='uncategorized')
        unset($terms[$index]);
    $has_category = (count($terms)>0);
  }
  return $has_category;
}
```

Note that my `has_category()` function treats posts with the `'uncategorized'` category as having no category. There are probably more performant ways to accomplish this but what you see above should work.

-Mike

Comment: What about `query_posts` with `category__in`?

Comment: @t31os - Probably. There are many roads that lead to Rome, this was just the one I chose to write about. :)

Comment: The downside to this method is that you don't always have the same number of posts per page. When you ignore a post you don't add an extra one at the end of the page.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - True.